# How to convert a promise to an observable in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, observable

Should I convert this google geocode method to an observable?

If so, how would I do it?

FYI - I don't think I need to reject the promise, just return a null, so I made that little change below.

```js
const geoCode = new Geocode();
geoCode.geocode('some address').then(place => {
  console.log(place.geometry.location);
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});


export class Geocode {

  geocode(address: string): Promise<any> {
    const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      geocoder.geocode({
          address: address
        },
        (results, status) => {
          if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            resolve(results[0]);
          } else {
            // reject(new Error(status)); // don't need to reject
            resolve(null);
          }
        }
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Promise to Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39319279/convert-promise-to-observable)

Comment: there's so many answers in your link, it's a little confusing/overwhelming. Not sure if any of the answers from the link help though as the code from the promise isn't shown, while my example has all the code from the promise.

Comment: well..read them, try the ones that seem to match your case and then let us know what specific problem you have

Comment: Maybe a better question would be, how would I wait for google goecoder in Angular 9/10? Promise or Observable?

Comment: like this one you mean ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56186253/how-to-wait-for-google-geocode-to-return-a-response

Comment: That is the link I got my code from, but it doesn't really talk about Observables. It only has a Promise as the solution. I'm not that familiar with Promises, only observables as I am new to Angular. I see that Promises are one time and Observables are like "streams". So not sure if either would be better for Google Geocode.

Comment: you don't provide us all the details, the things you have already search and expect a precise answer ? how about this other one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759593/how-do-i-wait-for-a-promise-to-finish-before-returning-the-variable-of-a-functio

Comment: Well, maybe I don't need anything! Maybe using a promise here is sufficient. I just thought it would be nice to use an Observable. I guess it doesn't really matter.

Comment: So you have not tested your code ?

Comment: No, I have, the code I posted does work. I guess I'm just exploring different options to see if there is something better. Just trying to understand Angular/Observables/Promises better.

Comment: I think I have decided on the best option. I'm going to put the Google Geocode call into a service and then subscribe to it. In my app. I have a input field where the client types in an address, presses enter or selects from a dropdown from Google Places autocomplete. If Google autocomplete doesn't fine anything, then I go and look for that address with Google Geocode. Autocomplete is a directive, so I think maybe Geocode should be a service, as I'm going to use it on multiple pages. At first I thought about putting Geocode in a ts file, but that's probably not the best solution. A service is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  geocode(address: string): Observable<any> {
    const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    return new Observable(subscriber => {
      geocoder.geocode({
          address: address
        },
        (results, status) => {
          if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            subscriber.next(results[0]);
          } else {
            subscriber.next(null);
          }
          subscriber.complete();
        }
      );
    });
  }
```